# Project Folder disappears after flutter build

Tags: android-studio, dart, flutter

After command "flutter build apk", android studio project shows only the External Libraries. Unable to run the application too.

Note: Flutter Run is working fine from the terminal.
[image]

Comment: Try building APK from the BUILD options on top instead of CLI, then you might  won't get this issue.

Comment: I just found that the files are excluded from the project module

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try File -> Sync with File System

If you still cant see it, I suggest importing your old project to a new one to save the hassle.

Comment: I just found that the files are excluded from the project module

Comment: there you go, not a big problem since your files can still be accessed an Flutter Run works.